# Leaflet only allows polygon layer from GeoJSON to be displayed one time

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson, ajax

I have used an AJAX call to load a Black Sea GeoJSON that I want to display as a polygon on the map.

```
var blackSea = [];
var blackSeaData = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("./blacksea.json");
blackSea.push(blackSeaData);

blackSea[0].addTo(map);
```

The first time I use `blackSea[0].addTo(map)` it works, the polygon is displayed, and I can even change its style, but if I clear the map with `clearMap()` and try it again it does not display. If I `clearMap()` before the initial call it still displays, but after I `clearMap()` again it does not.

What could be the problem here?

edit: the `clearMap()` function:

```
    function clearMap() {
    for(i in map._layers) {
        if(map._layers[i]._path != undefined) {
            try {
                map.removeLayer(map._layers[i]);
            }
            catch(e) {
                console.log("problem with " + e + map._layers[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ```map.hasLayer(blackSea[0])``` returns ```true```

Comment: Leaflet has no `.clearMap()` method, only `.clearLayers()`, which removes all layers from layer group.

Comment: Ah forgot I made that function, adding to the post.

Comment: In your function you are using Leaflet internal properties, which is practice you should absolutely avoid if possible. In your case you do not really know the nature of `map._layers` array and as a consequence probably removing all layers/features of `blackSeaData` group layer. If you want to remove all layers from the map, you can do that with simple call `map.eachLayer(function(layer) {map.removeLayer(layer);})`.

Comment: This preserves the Black Sea, but is there any way to call it without removing the tile map layer?

Comment: Simply set `if (layer !== tileLayer)` and it worked fine. Thank you!